# What's the difference between using a mixin and extend a component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When should I extend a component and when should I use mixin in Vue. Both bring all data and methods to the actual component.

Comment: Mixins are kind of an anti-pattern recently. Mixins are not documenting their functionality well, compared to extending another component. They just work magically and hopefully integrate well with your existing variables and functions.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to choose mixins reason because mixins are being used to add small chunks of functionality to a component while extend for a fully component to create a new component with additional or changed options.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).